# How to use HTML template with Vaadin?

Tags: html, templates, merge, vaadin

I am new to Vaadin.

I have created template for my web application in HTML and JS.

 How to use the developed template with Vaadin as am not sure if I will be able to develop same template using Vaadin only?

Comment: Don't use Vaadin if you already have HTML and JS that you want to use.

Comment: @Ingo: Yeah that true that, vaadin will also give same, but I have only template. Can you suggest what should be ideal way to proceed from here as still need to design other component and integrate with Backend? Your help is solicited

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be possible to re-use some of the layout of the template using the [CustomLayout](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.customlayout.html) layout component in Vaadin.

You can also render the contents of a template into a Label component, and display the label in the application. See http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler#LabelRich for a small demo.

Generally, though, the idea of templates and "pages" is orthogonal to developing applications in Vaadin.