# filling available space inside a vertical layout

Tags: layout, vaadin, vaadin7

in my vaadin project i have a vertical layout (with the height 100%), with two other vertical layouts inside. the fist one has a fixed height, while the second one should fill the remaining space of the browser-window. it will have a bigger height than the remaining space and has an overflow-y: scroll css-attribute. i tried this with the method setExpandRatio but did not work (the height was often more than the remaining space). can i achieve this just with vaadin, or do i have to use javascript for this?

```
AbstractOrderedLayout root = new VerticalLayout();
root.setHeight(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
AbstractOrderedLayout child1 = new VerticalLayout();   
AbstractOrderedLayout child2 = new VerticalLayout();  

child1.setHeight(200, Unit.PIXELS);
root.addComponent(child1);

child2.setHeightUndefined(); 
root.addComponent(child2); // child2 will be filled with items. if its higher than the remaining space, it should be scrollable (overflow-y: auto)
// root.setExpandRatio(child2, 1F);
```

Comment: "did not work" can mean anything.  care to elaborate on this?  for sane scrolling behaviour i'd rather go with a `Panel (100% height & 1 expandRatio) and place the layout within.

Comment: the second child gets longer than the remaining space when i add content to it. it is not cut as i expected it, and no scrollbars appear. the whole project is more complicated, i need VerticalLayout. i just removed everything unnecessary, to describe my problem.

Comment: have you tried with a Panel?

Comment: that would be quite much work, because the project is already quite advanced. anyway even without scrolling the problem is existing. child2 simple does not get "cut" with the overflow-y attribute, if i set it to hidden. child2 is as high as its content, and ignored the remaining space.

well if nothing helps i can try it with a panel, but it can not really understand why its height should behave different.

Comment: if i set the height of child2 to a fix pixel value, then everything is just as expected. there is only a problem with the hight calculation.

Comment: well it's hard to imagine, what you are after, if you only show the bare minimum of code here.  to my understanding the usecase here would be to have a fixed sized header area with 200px and a "content" area filling the remainder of the page and show scrollbars?

Comment: yes, exactly. thats what i want.
actually its just the left menu-part of the window. in the real code those components are custom components. it would not make it more clear to post the full code.

Comment: Then the same applies from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940668/vaadin-basic-layout-fixed-header-and-footer-scrollable-content .  Use a Panel.  The code change is about four lines.

Comment: just put child2 in your example above into a panel and add the panel instead of child2 to the root.  i really can not imagine a UI, where this would be such a showstopper...

Comment: wow, really it works. i could not believe before;-)
please write this information as answer so that i can mark your answer as right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if i've understood right you would like to have a first area with fixed height and a second area that could be bigger than remaining height so it needs to scroll.

If that's the case, here's the layout

- VerticalLayout"Main" (sizeFull)

  - VerticalLayout"1" (width 100%, height fixed): fill this layout with your fixed height content
  - Panel (sizeFull + setExpandRation on VerticalLayoutMain to 1)

    - VerticalLayout"2" (width100%, heightUndefined): fill this layout with your other content

Regards