# GridLayout - fill all available space in content

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I'm developing a web application in Vaadin framework which has home page and few sub pages. What I want to achieve is to have fixed header and footer and in the center have content, that is being changed and fill all the space between header and footer. This is my `MainUI` class:

```
// HEADER
final VerticalLayout headerLayout = new VerticalLayout();
final Panel headerPanel = new Panel();
headerPanel.addStyleName("header");

final ActiveLink header = new ActiveLink(provider.getText(getLocale(), "application.title.name"), new ExternalResource(""));
header.addStyleName("header");
header.addListener((ActiveLink.LinkActivatedListener) (ActiveLink.LinkActivatedEvent event) -> {
    getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(Constant.View.MAIN);
});

headerPanel.setContent(header);
headerLayout.addComponent(headerPanel);

// FOOTER
final VerticalLayout footerLayout = new VerticalLayout(new Label("« FOOTER »"));

// CONTENT
final VerticalLayout contentLayout = new VerticalLayout();

final Panel contentPanel = new Panel(contentLayout);
contentPanel.addStyleName("content transparent no-border");

// MAIN = all together
final VerticalLayout mainLayout = new VerticalLayout(headerLayout, contentPanel, footerLayout);
mainLayout.setSizeFull();
mainLayout.setExpandRatio(contentPanel, 1);
setContent(mainLayout);

// Register Views in navigator
navigator = new Navigator(this, contentPanel);
navigator.addView("", new MainView(provider));
navigator.addView(Constant.View.DICT_ADMIN, new DictAdminView(provider));
```

For changing the view in content I'm using `Navigator` like this in `MainView` class:

```
final ActiveLink link11 = new ActiveLink(provider.getText(getLocale(), "menu.links.dict.admin"), new ExternalResource(""));
link11.addStyleName("menulinks");
link11.addListener((LinkActivatedListener) (LinkActivatedEvent event1) -> {
    getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(Constant.View.DICT_ADMIN);
});
```

And finally this is my `DictAdminView` class:

```
public class DictAdminView extends GridLayout implements View {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DictAdminView.class);
    I18NProvider provider;
    private final DictionaryDao dictionaryDao = new DictionaryDao();
    private final TermDao termDao = new TermDao();
    private final JPAContainer dictionaries = dictionaryDao.getContainer();
    private final JPAContainer terms = termDao.getContainer();

    public DictAdminView(I18NProvider provider) {
        super(4, 6);
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
        removeAllComponents();
        this.addStyleName("dictAdminLayout");
        this.setSizeFull();
        this.setSpacing(true);

        // Table with Dictionaries
        Grid grid = new Grid(dictionaries);
        grid.setId("dictList");
        grid.setWidth("100%");
        grid.setColumns(
            grid.getColumns().get(1).getPropertyId(),
            grid.getColumns().get(0).getPropertyId());
        grid.getColumns().get(1).setWidth(80).setHeaderCaption("POS");
        this.addComponent(grid, 0, 0, 0, 5);
        dictionaries.sort(new Object[]{grid.getColumns().get(0).getPropertyId()}, new boolean[]{true});

        // Table with Terms
        Grid grid1 = new Grid(terms);
        grid1.setId("termList");
        grid1.setWidth("100%");
        grid1.setColumns(
            grid1.getColumns().get(5).getPropertyId(),
            grid1.getColumns().get(0).getPropertyId());
        this.addComponent(grid1, 1, 0, 3, 3);
        terms.sort(new Object[]{grid1.getColumns().get(0).getPropertyId()}, new boolean[]{true});
        terms.addContainerFilter(new IsNull("dictionaryId"));   // show items w/o dict by default

        this.addComponent(new Button("lol button"), 1, 5, 3, 5);

        // Handle dictionary selection
        grid.addSelectionListener(selectionEvent -> {
        // Get selection from the selection model
            Integer selectedDictionaryId = (Integer) ((SingleSelectionModel) grid.getSelectionModel()).getSelectedRow();

            terms.removeAllContainerFilters();

            if (selectedDictionaryId != null) {
                terms.addContainerFilter(new Compare.Equal("dictionaryId.id", selectedDictionaryId));
                Utils.showInfoMessage(provider.getText(getLocale(), "msg.info.title.dictionary.selected"),
                            grid.getContainerDataSource().getItem(selectedDictionaryId).getItemProperty("name").toString());
            }
            else {
                terms.addContainerFilter(new IsNull("dictionaryId"));   // show items w/o dict by default
                Utils.showInfoMessage(provider.getText(getLocale(), "msg.info.title.nothing.selected"), "");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My problem here is that I can't stretch the `Grid` to fill all space between header and footer. I've tried combination of `setSizeFull()` and `setRowExtendRatio()` but no success. Also I've tried to do it in CSS.

1. Is there a way how to stretch the grid either in Java or CSS?
2. Is the `Navigator` and changing `View` a good approach or is there a better way how to switch between content?

Comment: I think you mix up here grid and gridlayout. You can use the BorderLayout for such cases. https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/borderlayout

Comment: this this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940668/vaadin-basic-layout-fixed-header-and-footer-scrollable-content.  the way in general is, have the outer layout setSizeFull and and expand your "main" component then.  if you want scrolling with a panel, set the content of that panel to undefined size.  view/navigator is fine, but if you have static content you might want to use a ViewDisplay, which makes it easier to exchange parts only.

Comment: Another possibility would be [CustomLayout](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/layout/layout-customlayout.html) where you could define div-tags for header, footer and content area and style by CSS.

Comment: @AndréSchild Yes, I meant stretching `Grid` that is inside. I finally used `BorderLayout` which solved my issue quickly. In more complicated case I would use `CustomLayout` and write it all in HTML+CSS. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use Vaadin add-on [BorderLayout](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/borderlayout) or built-in `CustomLayout` with own HTML and CSS.